# PayPal Sandbox Express Checkout - "You've been inactive for a while, so we logged you out"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have code to handle the PayPal Express Checkout for invoices on our site, basically a version of this:

[Paypal Checkout Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)

This code was working fine earlier this week. But now when my PayPal button opens the window to log into PayPal, I am getting this message from the PayPal sandbox site: "You've been inactive for a while, so we logged you out to help protect your account." This has happened to me on Chrome and Firefox. I cleared my cookies out on Chrome and still got the message. I logged into crossbrowsertesting.com and tried it on Firefox there and still got the message. My code hasn't changed since I tested it earlier this week. Does anyone have any suggestions for what's going on and what I can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you change the settings for the PayPal payment module and enter the email address for the sandbox account to receive the payment and also ensure "sandbox" or "test" mode is enabled.

If the issuer persists, share the exact error message and if possible, a PayPal debug id.